# How to display the website page in safari to the full height of the device display

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, web-applications

When you add a site to the iPhone home screen and then open it, the Safari browser menu disappears. Instead of the menu, there is a black space.[Safari screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGGZR.jpg)

How to display the page to the full height of the device display?

Answer (score -1):

Choose Safari > Settings for [website] and choose an option from the Page Zoom pop-up menu, or choose View > Zoom In. Then you can take screenshot.

Comment: I don't need to take a screenshot. I want to open the site from my home screen without that black space.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).